# Using OpenSSL's CMS implementation in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, openssl

So my project today has been to create a C++ class that consolidates a lot of our commonly used crypto tasks. Got lots of things working but ran into a bit of a snag here. For reference, I'm using XCode 3.2.5 on OS 10.6.5.

I'm attempting to utilize some of OpenSSL's CMS functions. [OpenSSL's MAN Page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/CMS_sign.html) for one of the functions I'm trying to use mentions it was included in version 0.9.8. That's the version XCode let me import without having to do anything out of the ordinary (Target -> General -> Add Linked Library). Yet with that added XCode tells me it can't find openssl/cms.h.

So thinking maybe there's some disparity between the OS X version 0.9.8 and the one on OpenSSLs page, I downloaded the source for 1.0.0c and built it. After it was built, I added libcrypto.a and libssl.a to my project as linked libraries and added "some/dirs/openssl-1.0.0c/include/**" as a header search path. Now it can find openssl/cms.h but I get a linking error on any CMS function I call.

Has anyone done this successfully? Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was to create a new SDK and calling,

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/path/to/sdk/usr --openssldir=/System/Library/OpenSSL enable-cms shared
```

To update the version of OpenSSL included in that SDK. That's seemed to work.